# rows and columns not working bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

i'm trying to use rows and columns but it's not working, a new row isn't created, it just fills the width of the row before starting a new row. I tried it with chrome and safari and it is not working on both of them.

```
                          <div class="container">
                    <div class="row" id='bsoon'>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 thumbs item-thumbs bedroomcloset mattress chair accessory">
                            <p>Coming soon</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                                  <h3>The City</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                            <div class="name" hidden>TheCity</div>
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" id="fbox" rel="city" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/full/image-01-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <img align="middle" src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-01.jpg" alt="This kitchen features unadorned minimalism that’s fresh, relaxing and welcoming thanks to the white and yellow glossy paint. Handless drawers and Doors with soft opening and closing mechanism enabling drawers to open and shut smoothly." style="margin-top:-60px">
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                            <div class="name" hidden>TheCity</div>
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" rel="city" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/full/image-08-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <img  src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-08.jpg" alt="This kitchen features unadorned minimalism that’s fresh, relaxing and welcoming thanks to the white and yellow glossy paint. Handless drawers and Doors with soft opening and closing mechanism enabling drawers to open and shut smoothly.">
                                 </div>
                             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                            <div class="name" hidden>TheCity</div>
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" rel="city" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/full/image-08-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-08.jpg" alt="This kitchen features unadorned minimalism that’s fresh, relaxing and welcoming thanks to the white and yellow glossy paint. Handless drawers and Doors with soft opening and closing mechanism enabling drawers to open and shut smoothly.">
                            </div>
                                </div>
                        <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">          
                                 <h3>The Executive</h3>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                            <div class="name" hidden>TheExecutive</div>
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" rel="exec" title="The Executive" href="_include/img/work/full/image-02-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-02.jpg" alt="The perfect contrast of graphite mirror-like doors with the warmth of Ebony veneer made even more stunning with the two-level black and (glow-in-the-dark) worktops, where the island brings the working surface close to the family, and sets the scene on center stage: seating at the grey metallic bar is symbolic of a new togetherness.">
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                             <div class="name" hidden>TheExecutive</div>
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" rel="exec" title="The Executive" href="_include/img/work/full/image-09-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-09.jpg" alt="The perfect contrast of graphite mirror-like doors with the warmth of Ebony veneer made even more stunning with the two-level black and (glow-in-the-dark) worktops, where the island brings the working surface close to the family, and sets the scene on center stage: seating at the grey metallic bar is symbolic of a new togetherness.">
                            </div>
        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                                <h3>The Arctic</h3>
                            </div>
                         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                            <div class="name" hidden>TheArctic</div>
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" rel="arc" title="The Arctic" href="_include/img/work/full/image-05-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-05.jpg" alt="A kitchen of pure fashion creativity. A functional design without handles, with full extension drawer slides to avoid excess bending. The mirror- like blue arcylic tall units communicate with the zebrano laminate elements, creating a combination of closed and open shelves.">
                            </div>
                         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                            <div class="name" hidden>TheArctic</div>
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" rel="arc" title="The Arctic" href="_include/img/work/full/image-06-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-06.jpg" alt="A kitchen of pure fashion creativity. A functional design without handles, with full extension drawer slides to avoid excess bending. The mirror- like blue arcylic tall units communicate with the zebrano laminate elements, creating a combination of closed and open shelves.">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                                 <h3>The Vavona</h3>
                            </div>
                         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbs item-thumbs kitchen">
                            <div class="name" hidden>TheVavona</div>
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" rel="vavona" title="The Vavona" href="_include/img/work/full/image-03-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-03.jpg" alt="Power through contrast, when very different refined materials and original colours enter into symbiosis, big things happen. The island is enhanced with a black top accommodating a ceramic hob and a hood in the center of the room where you can enjoy the experience of cooking in the atmosphere of fresh orange colour, brown metallic laminate and the exotic Vavona wood!!">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Edit

I found when inspecting that there's something that adds the following inline styling which causes that problem

```
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? Specifically, "a new row isn't created, it just fills the width of the row before starting a new row" doesn't make sense as this is expected behavior.

Comment: @Skelly The columns' sum isn't equal to 12 in each row. but i want a new row to be created even if the columns doesn't take the full width

Comment: The row seems to be working as expected: http://www.codeply.com/go/ZhbVKzYPYW

Comment: it doesn't work for me here's a screenshot http://postimg.org/image/q0nfnjoxd/

Comment: That looks different than the code you posted. There are most likely other CSS styles that are creating the wrap.

Comment: i can't find it would you like my to post the css styling?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It creates 4 rows and 4 columns (if that's what you're looking for).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Make sure you have this inside your header `<head>`.

```
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: it didn't work for me i don't know why here is a screenshot http://postimg.org/image/tph9ht7if/

Comment: Make sure you have the correct bootstrap reference in your header. I have edited my answer to include that. Try that and let me know.

Comment: i have edited my original post please check. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

The whole problem is from the isotope.js layoutmode which forced the elements to fit into rows

the solution is to create a 'none' layoutmode element and assign it in the isotope

```
  var NoneMode = Isotope.LayoutMode.create('none');
        $container.isotope({
        layoutMode: 'none',
        });
```